# Caching a resultset

Tags: spring, caching, jdbc, jakarta-ee, scalability

My app will retrieve a countylist from MySql using a datasource bean. Since all pages will potentially use the same recordset every time I could store the countrylist as a List in some global bean, safe in this case. I could manage to refresh the list any time I want... but when things become more complex what is the best strategy for it, the more scalable solution?

Use a in memory database? 
A 3rd part cached resultset?

didnt found one, probably because I'm to new to the subject.

Comment: What do you mean with "more complex"? What do you mean with "refresh anytime"? Is the data changed everytime *externally*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultSet` is tied to the database connection, it's a fairly ephemeral construct, and not suitable for caching.

I recommend using [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) to cache your results. It's an in-memory cache mechanism (with options to overflow to disk, and options to distribute across a cluster). It integrates very nicely with Spring (via `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` and `EhCacheFactoryBean`).

Comment: not much time to test, but I will give a try! just saw a little article explaining its basics, but the basic need a bit of preparation. anyway, its said to be scalable and like you said goes well with spring. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the country list is updated almost never, fill a [FastMap](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastMap.html) on application startup with the map keys being the [two letter country abbreviations](http://www.greenbuilder.com/general/countries.html) and the values being other info you want to store for each country. Otherwise, use an in-memory DB cache such as EhCache and Memcached.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html).  It can be treated like a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), but it doesn't need to maintain a connection to the database.